# Given squares $M$ and $N$ are inscribed in a right triangle $ABC.$ If area$(M)=441$ and area$(N)=440,$ then find area of the triangle $ABC.$

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations, triangles, area

> Given squares $M$ and $N$ are inscribed in right triangle $ABC$ as shown in fig. If the area of $M$ is $441$ and area of $N$ is $440$, then find the area of the triangle $ABC.$

[image: 1]

My attempt:  I did some lengthy calculation and I ended up with the equation

$k^3-882k^2-400k+400×441=0$

Where $k=ab, a=BC, b=AC$

Comment: By drawing you cansee that area of ABC is 880 for square 440 and 882 for square 441.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ and $y$ be a sides-lengths of the squares with areas $M$ and $N$ respectively.

Thus, by the similarity we obtain:
$$\frac{x}{b}=\frac{a-x}{a}$$ and $$\frac{\frac{ab}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}-y}{\frac{ab}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}}=\frac{y}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},$$  which gives
$$x=\frac{ab}{a+b}$$ and $$y=\frac{ab\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{a^2+ab+b^2}.$$
Thus, $$a+b=\frac{k}{21}$$ and we obtain:
$$\frac{k\sqrt{\frac{k^2}{441}-2k}}{\frac{k^2}{441}-k}=\sqrt{440}$$ or
$$\frac{\sqrt{\frac{k^2}{441}-2k}}{\frac{k}{441}-1}=\sqrt{440}$$ or
$$441(k^2-2\cdot441k)=440(k-441)^2$$ or
$$441(k-441)^2-441^3=440(k-441)^2$$ or
$$(k-441)^2=\left(21^3\right)^2,$$ which gives $$k-441=21^3$$ or
$$k=9702$$ and the area is equal to $4851.$

Comment: That much i had done the tough part is after this if you solve for finding ab you will find that equation which i had written

Comment: @anonymous Kumar I think you wrote a cubic equation. No? But my equation is quadratic.

Comment: @anonymous Kumar I wrote a full solution. See now.

Comment: I think i made some mistakes thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

We deduce easily (from the left triangle) that $a+b=ab/\sqrt{M}$ hence
$$(a+b)^2=\frac{(ab)^2}{M}.$$

Now consider the right triangle; its area is $ab/2$.  Let $c^2=a^2+b^2$. It consists of three triangles and a square. The area of the upper left triangle equals due to similarity
$$\frac12ab\frac{N}{a^2},$$ analogue for the other two triangles.  Let's sum up:
$$\frac12ab\frac{N}{a^2}+\frac12ab\frac{N}{b^2}+\frac12ab\frac{N}{c^2}+N=\frac12ab$$
that is
$$N\left(\frac{b}{a}+\frac ab+\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2} \right)+2N=ab.$$
Observe that
$$\frac{b}{a}+\frac ab=\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab}=\frac{(a+b)^2}{ab}-2=\frac{ab}{M}-2$$
exploiting $(a+b)^2=\frac{(ab)^2}{M}$.

Solving the quadratic
$$N\left(\frac{ab}{M}-2+\frac{1}{\frac{ab}{M}-2}\right)+2N=ab$$
for $ab$ gives the positive solution
$$ab=M-\frac{M^2}{\sqrt{M(M-N)}}.$$

In the special case $N=M-1$ we arrive in $ab=M(1+\sqrt M)$ so if $M=441$ we get $ab=9702$.